# MySQL change select output with data from other row

Tags: php, mysql

I'm sorry if I don't know the correct terminology but here we go:

I have a table with the following columns and rows:

```
------------------------------
| id    | parent_id  | type  |
------------------------------
| 1     | 0          | text1 |
| 2     | 1          | text2 |
------------------------------
```

Now what I want is to select the type, but if the `parent_id` is not 0
I want the type to be the content of the type from it's parent +[ the type of itself ].

So the output for a select would in this case be:

```
----------------
| type         |
----------------
| text1        |
| text1[text2] |
----------------
```

I was trying this with a concat and an if statement, but couldn't figure this out.

Can you help me out?

Comment: Will this only be for the immediate parent, or do you want to include the ultimate ancestor? (The latter is problematic in MySQL.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
select c.id,
       case c.parent_id 
            when 0 then c.type
            else concat(p.type,'[',c.type,']')
       end as type
from mytable c
left join mytable p on c.parent_id = p.id
```

SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e4f7ec/3).

Comment: shouldn't be `case parent_id` there?

Comment: Super thanks!
Now can you also do a where here? or is this not possible because of the if statement in there?

Comment: @BonifatiusK: You should be able to do a `where` here.